# How can I eliminate vertical space between rows of buttons in an HTML table?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` that pops up when the "PATTERNS" `button` is pressed. This `div` holds a `table` of `buttons` (see pic). I want all of the `buttons` to be touching however I can't seem to get rid of the row spaces in between them. I am not an experienced `html` `table` user.

[image]

My research has led me to try the following, is my `table` layout optimal here?:

```css
.ButtonTable {
  display: block;
  background: rgb(116, 116, 116);
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 2%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 70%;
  /*BOX HEIGHT*/
  z-index: 1002;
  overflow: auto;
  opacity: .80;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.PatternButton {
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 200px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table className="ButtonTable" cellspacing="0">
  <td className="Col12">
    <th className="Title1">col1</th>
    <button className="PatternButton">1</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">2</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">3</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">4</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">5</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">6</button><br></br>
    <th className="Title2">col2</th>
    <button className="PatternButton">1</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">2</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">3</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">4</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">5</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">6</button><br></br>
  </td>
  <td className="Col34">
    <th className="Title3">col3</th>
    <button className="PatternButton">1</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">2</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">3</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">4</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">5</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">6</button><br></br>
    <th className="Title4">col4</th>
    <button className="PatternButton">1</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">2</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">3</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">4</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">5</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">6</button><br></br>
  </td>
  <td className="Col5">
    <th className="Title5">col5</th>
    <button className="PatternButton">1</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">2</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">3</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">4</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">5</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">6</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">7</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">8</button><br></br>
  </td>
  <td className="Col6">
    <th className="Title6">col6</th>
    <button className="PatternButton">1</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">2</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">3</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">4</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">5</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">6</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">7</button><br></br>
    <button className="PatternButton">8</button><br></br>
  </td>
</table>
```

Comment: cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"

Comment: Thank you but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Maybe there is a border on the buttons, try styling the buttons. eg. `.PatternButton { border: none; }`

Comment: That helped the column gap! But the row gaps are still there. I added my `.PatternButton` styling to the question.

Comment: FYI, this isn't a valid use case for a table anyway. Tables should be used for tabular data, not layout.

Comment: Short Answer is no, your table layout is not optimal, className is Unecessary & should be just class plus your using two line breaks for each button, which are text elements, not generally used for layout, plus td should be inside tr's... You could also shorten PatternButton to => PtrnBtn...

Comment: filter: alpha(opacity=80); this line in your css is also, not great you can use filter:opacity(value); Where the value is a decimal number between 0 + 1, ie 0.7, 0 being transparent and 1 being fully opaque(or solid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: **YOU NEED TO UNDERSTAND WHAT YOUR DID WRONG**

Mistake: 
You used `<br>` to break line after every button, thus creating that extra space.
Here: `<button className="PatternButton">1</button><br></br>`

Solution:
Remove the line break `<br>` and set  `display: block` for your buttons and they'll line up as a column.

```css
.ButtonTable {
    display: block;
    background: rgb(116, 116, 116);
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: 2%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 70%; /*BOX HEIGHT*/
    z-index: 1002;
    overflow: auto;
    opacity: .80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    border-spacing:0;
    border-collapse: collapse;    
}
.PatternButton {
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 200px;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* just for illustration I've added the following */
    padding: 15px;
    display: block;  
    border: thin solid grey; 
}
```

```html
<!-- Just recreated the HTML so tat I can format it on html, and not jsx -->
<table class="ButtonTable" cellspacing="0">                     
  <td class="Col12">    
    <button class="PatternButton">1</button>
    <button class="PatternButton">1</button>
    <button class="PatternButton">1</button>
    <button class="PatternButton">1</button>
    <button class="PatternButton">1</button>
    <button class="PatternButton">1</button>
    <button class="PatternButton">1</button>
    <button class="PatternButton">1</button>
  </td>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your reply. I was wondering why `display: block` wasn't working and it was because of the `<br>` tags. Really appreciate your response

Comment: Great stuff. I am glad I was able to help, good luck @jayjey.

Answer (score 3):

I think I understand what you are asking. Try wrapping the buttons in divs and setting the margins.

https://jsfiddle.net/25wognuf/

```
   <style>
   .wr {
     margin: -1px -1px 10px -1px;
    padding: 0px;
   }
   </style>


<table className="ButtonTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">    
<tr>
  <td className="Col12">
    <div class="wr">
    <button className="PatternButton">1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="wr">
    <button className="PatternButton">2</button>
    </div>
</td> 
  <td className="Col12">
    <div class="wr">
    <button className="PatternButton">1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="wr">
    <button className="PatternButton">2</button>
    </div>
 </td>
</tr>                   
</table>
```

Comment: Great! This worked. I used `margin: -1px -1px -20px -1px`. Thank you for your help. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `line-height` of `<br/>` elements to remove row spaces ... like this:

```
br {
  line-height: 0;
}
```